# Fatal error: Class 'CakeNumber' don't found

Tags: cakephp, installation, cakephp-2.0

I try run this project, but I get an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'CakeNumber' not found in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/cakephp-2.3.10/app/Controller/AppController.php on
>   line 76

I put

```
App::uses 'CakeNumber';
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import this Helper like this:

```
App::uses('CakeNumber', 'Utility');
```

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/number.html